# To enable MFA for specific apps registered in okta through api

Tags: okta, okta-api, multi-factor-authentication

I want to enable Multi Factor Authentication for specific apps registered in okta through api.I found Factors api but in that the MFA was enabled for a user. I want to enable MFA for some specific apps only. Is there a way to enable MFA for certain applications through api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application sign on policies to enable MFA enrolment at application level. You can find more details below:

https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Security/App_Based_Signon.htm